# CakePHP Parent_ID Name

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

My DB

STUDENT TABLE

```
ID    NAME     PARENT_ID (VARCHAR)
1     JOHN     NULL
2     MATT     NULL
3     PETER    1,2
```

Display in a list of Table

```
ID    NAME     MENTOR NAME
1     JOHN     NULL
2     MATT     NULL
3     PETER    JOHN, MATT
```

How can I display "John and Matt instead of "1,2" when creating a for each loop to display the list of data on a table?

I've a StudentExtra in my Student Class within the $belongTo to display the mentor name. However, this method shows only one mentor name.

MODEL

```
class Student extends AppModel
{
// Mainly for PHP4 users
var $name = 'Student';
var $hasMany = array('Order','Test'); 

var $belongsTo = array
(
'StudentExtra'=>array
(
   'className'  => 'Student',
   'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
),'School','Classroom'
);
```

CONTROLLER

```
    $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 10,
        'order' => array('Student.name' => 'ASC'));

    $this->set('students', $this->paginate('Student'));
```

VIEW

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($students as $student){ ?>
<tr> 
<td>
<?php $student['Student']['id'] ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>
<?php $student['Student']['name'] ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>
<?php $student['Student']['parent_id'] ?>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

**RESULT**

```
 Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [Student] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1190
                [customers_gender] => M
                [resumetest] => 
                [created] => 2013-04-01 19:29:08
                [modified] => 2013-04-01 19:29:08
                [customers_name] => aaa aaa
                [customers_dob] => 1970-01-01
                [customers_roles] => student
                [customers_types] => student
                [customers_parent_id] => 1055,1056
                [school_id] => 40
                [classroom_id] => 96
            )

        [StudentExtra] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1055
                [customers_gender] => F
                [created] => 2013-03-28 11:14:25
                [modified] => 2013-03-28 11:14:25
                [customers_name] => Mich
                [customers_dob] => 1970-01-01
                [customers_roles] => teacher
                [customers_types] => teacher
                [customers_parent_id] => 
                [school_id] => 40
                [classroom_id] => 96
            )

        [School] => Array
            (
                [id] => 40
                [name] => Primary School
                [description] => 
                [created] => 2013-03-28 10:47:05
                [modified] => 2013-03-28 10:47:05
            )

        [Classroom] => Array
            (
                [id] => 96
                [name] => 30G
                [year_level] => 3
                [description] => 
                [created] => 2013-03-28 10:58:25
                [modified] => 2013-03-28 10:58:25
                [school_id] => 40
            )

        [Order] => Array
            (
            )

        [Test] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Are you using CakePHP 1.3, 1.2 or 2.1? There's a big difference and you just included every tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other cakephp way is as below.

You can also set association to **Student model** as below.

In **Student Model** add below code

```
var $belongsTo = array
(
    'StudentExtra'=>array
    (
       'className'  => 'Student',
       'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    )
);
```

**In controller**

```
$this->set('students', $this->paginate('Student'));
```

Now just do a `pr($students); exit();` to test result in view or at the end of controller function.

**You will see extra appended record array for StudentExtra which is all you need.**

Now in view file display it as below.

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($students as $student){ ?>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <?php $student['Student']['id'] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <?php $student['Student']['name'] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <?php $student['StudentExtra']['name'] ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

**Answer Update response Code**

```
$this->paginate = array
(
    'joins'=>array
    (
        array
        (
            'table'=>'students',
            'alias'=>'StudentExtra',
            'type' =>'inner',
            'conditions' =>array('StudentExtra.id IN (Student.parent_id)')
        )
    ),
    'limit'=> 10,
    'order' => array('Student.name' => 'ASC')
);

$this->set('students', $this->paginate('Student'));
debug($this->paginate('Student'));
exit;
```

Comment: OMG! Dipesh You're equally awesome! You've solved my problem! I can go and sleep now! Thanks!

Comment: Dipesh, what if i got two parents ID associate to the student? can you help please? is like 90,20 (parent_id) -> 50 (student_id) i need to display two parents names.

Comment: @user1533321 then i will say its can not be possible because child only has one direct parent...just like human..

Comment: thanks for your reply. Dipesh do you have any solution to my problem?

Comment: @user1533321 change `belongsTo` to `hasMany` see if its help

Comment: thanks dipesh. It's very late here already. I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Dipesh. it's doesnt work. Notice (8): Undefined index: customers_name [APP/views/customers/admin_index.ctp, line 121]

Code | Context

                    </td> 
                    <td>
                     <?php echo $customer['StudentExtra']['customers_name']; ?>

Comment: @user1533321 does `StudentExtra` table has `customers_name` field..?

Comment: thanks dipesh. $student['StudentExtra']['customers_name']. i don't have a StudentExtra table. i got only have the student table. in order to show the teacher name you asked me to create a StudentExta on my model to show the teacher name rather than the teacher id.

Comment: currently, i've two teachers allocated to one student. therefore, the previous method doesnt show "more than one teacher". it only show the first teacher name.

Comment: @user1533321 `StudentExtra` is for example you need to choose `alias `as per table name...and make sure its related with `foreign-keys`..

Comment: @user1533321 okay to get more related record use `hasMany` association.

Comment: i tried to move the studentExtra to hasMany. it displayed Undefined index: customers_name [APP/views/customers/admin_index.ctp, line 121] Code | Context </td> <td> <?php echo $customer['StudentExtra']['customers_name']; ?>...

Comment: @user1533321 i suggest you to update your question with all the new code you have now and all the table structure.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! appreciate it! Warning (512): SQL Error: 1066: Not unique table/alias: 'StudentExtra' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 512] ?

Comment: @user1533321 ohhh please rename StudentExtra from paginate join to StudentMore and see

Comment: Debugger::Dump on which variable?

Comment: $this->paginate('Student')

Answer (score 1):

Create a students model:

```
class Students extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = false;

    public function getParentName($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $sql = "
            SELECT NAME FROM `students` WHERE ID = (
                SELECT PARENT_ID FROM `students` WHERE ID = $id
            )
        ");
        return $this->query($sql);
    }

}
```

Then in your controller:

```
$this->Students->getParentName(2); // in this case for Peter
```

Comment: Do you know how to use this type of statement? $this->Student->find('all', array('conditions' => array('' = '')));

Comment: @user1533321, No but I don't think it is possible to use in this situation. You need of a subquery there, so running the query yourself is like the simplest way.

Comment: jeffrey don't mind can you look at my edited qns again? Can you guide me getting name of the parent_id rather showing the parent_id itself.

Comment: thanks so much jeff. nearly there. SELECT name FROM 'students' WHERE ID = (SELECT parent_id FROM 'students' WHERE ID = 173) I got an error - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''students' WHERE ID = (SELECT parent_id FROM 'parents' WHERE ID = ' at line 1

Comment: can I have this in the view instead? $this->Students->getParentName(2);

Comment: @user1533321, for the error: you have to use the `\`` back ticks not `'`. For the view question: try it.

Comment: i tried to remove all the ' and it works! thanks jeff! awesome! please guide me to use $this->Students->getParentName(2); in view.. thanks in advance!

Comment: @user1533321, [learn it here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Views.html)

Comment: in controller $this->set('tnames', $this->Customer->getParentName(172)); in view echo $tnames; it displayed array not the name...

Comment: @user1533321, do `$tnames['NAME']` in view.

Comment: i tried your method earlier on. it's not working jeff. sigh... almost there... Notice (8): Undefined index: name [APP/views/students/admin_index.ctp, line 110]

Comment: @user1533321, I said `NAME` not `name`: `$tnames['NAME']`

Comment: do i need to use a for each to expand the array?

Comment: @user1533321, do `var_dump($tnames)` in the view and tell me the result.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["students"]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(17) "Peter" } } }

Comment: @user1533321, then do `$tnames[0]['name']`.